# Are there versions other than DRB have (priest) instead of (high priest) in Hebrews 2:17?

Tags: hebrews

I looked about 30 versions of English Bible, of Hebrews 2:17, I found all of them have (high priest) or (chief priest). Only DRB has (priest), the Latin Vulgate has (pontifex).

(pontifex)=member of the principal college of priests.

Hebrews 2:17 (DRB):

> Wherefore it behoved him in all things to be made like unto his brethren, that he might become a merciful and **faithful priest** before God, that he might be a propitiation for the sins of the people.

Hebrews 2:17 Latin Vulgate:

> 17. unde debuit per omnia fratribus similare ut misericors fieret et **fidelis pontifex** ad Deum ut repropitiaret delicta populi

Are there versions other than DRB have (priest), not (high priest)?

Wycliffe Bible has: a faithful **bishop**.

DRB (Douay-Rheims Bible) has (high priest) as translation of (pontificem) of the Latin Vulgate of Hebrews 3:1.

Thus, Hebrews 2:17, pontifex=priest. DRB.
Hebrews 3:1, pontificem=high priest. DRB.

Comment: The original Greek is αρχιερευς, Strong 749. [Thayer](https://biblehub.com/greek/749.htm)  renders this as 'chief priest' or 'high priest'. The Greek word αρχιερευς is applied to both Caiaphas and Annas in both Mark and Acts. The prefix αρχ- would indicate that it is not just a priest but an high priest or chief priest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Greek word (in Heb 2:17) ἀρχιερεὺς (archiereus) means "leading priest" or more commonly, "high priest".

The etymology of the Latin "pontifex" is highly disputed.  Its most probably original meaning was "maker of roads and bridges".  It was a title originally used by the Caesars who also added the epithet, "maximus".  Thus, their title, "Pontifex Maximus" means "greatest builder of roads and bridges".

This title was much prized by the medieval popes as is obvious from the countless inscriptions all over the Vatican.

"pontifex" is used in the Latin rather sparingly (eg, John 18:3, 13, etc).  In most occasions, "priest" is translated as "sacerdotum"; and "high priest" as "principis sacerdotum" (eg, Matt 26:3, 51, 57, 58, 62, 53, 65, etc).  Thus, the Latin is inconsistent and the DRB reflects this.

Even the Jerusalem Bible (translated from the Latin) uses "high priest" as does the NAB (a Catholic Bible) as well.
I can find no explanation for this inconsistency in the Latin text.

Comment: are there versions other than DRB having "priest", not "high priest"?, Anyway, thank you for your great effort.+1.

Comment: could you include the comment in your answer?

Comment: do you mean inconsistency in DRB?

Comment: I mean that the Latin is inconsistent and the DRB faithfully reproduces this inconsistency.

Comment: the Latin word is "pontifex" means, clearly, "high priest". Look Hebrews 3:1 in DRB and the Latin Vulgate. DRB sometimes be unfaithful to Latin Vulgate. Pontifex=high priest.

Comment: … except that where the Latin wanted to express this, it would often write "pontifex maximus", hence the Pope's title.

Comment: pontifex maximus=archbishop,  pontifex=bishop,  sacerdotum=priest. I hope my words are clear.

Comment: That is modern Catholic practice,  Here we are discussing Bible translations.  Most of the time, the Latin uses "principis sacerdotum" for "high priest".

Comment: that's it, principis sacerdotum=high priest, i.e: sacerdotum=priest. Pontifex=bishop, look Wycliffe Bible, Hebrews 2:17.

Comment: could you include the last comments in the answer, including the unfaithfulness of DRB sometimes to the Latin Vulgate.

Comment: I did not say this.  I said that the Latin is inconsistent and the DRB reflects this inconsistency.

Comment: I say: DRB is **Sometimes** unfaithful to the Latin Vulgate. You can add summary of the comments to the answer.

Comment: the discussion is very rich, I hope you include it in the answer, exhibiting your and my point of view.